# Convert all data frame character columns to factors

Tags: r, dataframe

Given a (pre-existing) data frame that has columns of various types, what is the simplest way to convert all its character columns to factors, without affecting any columns of other types?

Here's an example `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(A = factor(LETTERS[1:5]),
                 B = 1:5, C = as.logical(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)),
                 D = letters[1:5],
                 E = paste(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5]),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df
#   A B     C D   E
# 1 A 1  TRUE a A a
# 2 B 2  TRUE b B b
# 3 C 3 FALSE c C c
# 4 D 4 FALSE d D d
# 5 E 5  TRUE e E e
str(df)
# 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ B: int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ C: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
#  $ D: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#  $ E: chr  "A a" "B b" "C c" "D d" ...
```

I know I can do:

```
df$D <- as.factor(df$D)
df$E <- as.factor(df$E)
```

Is there a way to automate this process a bit more?

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
DF <- data.frame(x=letters[1:5], y=1:5, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

str(DF)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ x: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

You can use `as.data.frame` to turn all character columns into factor columns:

```
DF <- as.data.frame(unclass(DF),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
str(DF)
#'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
# $ x: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
# $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: As of a recent version of R, this is no longer necessarily true.  The best option appears to be to set the `stringsAsFactors` argument to `TRUE` in the call to `as.data.frame()`.  https://developer.r-project.org/Blog/public/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/

Comment: Why is the default from as.dato.frame annoying? Seems easy and handy to use

Comment: @RenéMartínez The default has been changed. More often than not, you don't want to transform character columns to factors.

Answer (score 124):

Roland's answer is great for this specific problem, but I thought I would share a more generalized approach.

```
DF <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5], y = 1:5, z = LETTERS[1:5], 
                 stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(DF)
# 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
#  $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ z: chr  "A" "B" "C" "D" ...

## The conversion
DF[sapply(DF, is.character)] <- lapply(DF[sapply(DF, is.character)], 
                                       as.factor)
str(DF)
# 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
#  $ y: int  1 2 3 4 5
#  $ z: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

For the conversion, the left hand side of the assign (`DF[sapply(DF, is.character)]`) subsets the columns that are character. In the right hand side, for that subset, you use `lapply` to perform whatever conversion you need to do. R is smart enough to replace the original columns with the results.

The handy thing about this is if you wanted to go the other way or do other conversions, it's as simple as changing what you're looking for on the left and specifying what you want to change it to on the right.

Comment: Thanks, very useful, especially after a RMySQL request that gives a dataframe of only character vectors. Just don't forget (like me) to set the proper type of numeric logical, etc. in the columns that are not character beforehand.

Comment: I like that answer. Partly because it's a more thorough solution, and partly because is the most involved use of lapply an sapply I've seen. I'll learn a bit more from that one!

Comment: You are a legend man! Thank you, I was searching for this for the last 1-2 days.

Answer (score 63):

As @Raf Z commented on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668266/dplyr-change-many-data-types), dplyr now has mutate_if.  Super useful, simple and readable.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ C: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 $ D: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ E: chr  "A a" "B b" "C c" "D d" ...

> df <- df %>% mutate_if(is.character,as.factor)

> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ C: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 $ D: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ E: Factor w/ 5 levels "A a","B b","C c",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```

Answer (score 14):

Working with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(A = factor(LETTERS[1:5]),
                 B = 1:5, C = as.logical(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)),
                 D = letters[1:5],
                 E = paste(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5]),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

str(df)
```

we get:

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ C: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 $ D: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ E: chr  "A a" "B b" "C c" "D d" ...
```

Now, we can convert all `chr` to `factors`:

```
df <- df%>%mutate_if(is.character, as.factor)
str(df)
```

And we get:

```
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ C: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 $ D: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ E: chr  "A a" "B b" "C c" "D d" ...
```

Let's provide also other solutions:

With base package:

```
df[sapply(df, is.character)] <- lapply(df[sapply(df, is.character)], 
                                                           as.factor)
```

With `dplyr` 1.0.0

```
df <- df%>%mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character))
```

With `purrr` package:

```
library(purrr)

df <- df%>% modify_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

Comment: I am using the line that you used with dplyr 1.0.0 which works (thanks!), but then when I try to change the columns to mutate (e.g. 1:3) or the function (e.g. as.numeric) it fails! What am I not getting, should't it be easy to change the parameters a bit?

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use the code given below. It would automate the whole process of converting all the variables as factors in a dataframe in R. it worked perfectly fine for me. food_cat here is the dataset which I am using. Change it to the one which you are working on.

```
    for(i in 1:ncol(food_cat)){

food_cat[,i] <- as.factor(food_cat[,i])

}
```

Comment: This will change All columns to factor, regardless of their type.

Answer (score 1):

I used to do a simple `for` loop. As @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 answer, `lapply` is a nice solution. But if you convert all the columns, you will need a `data.frame` before, otherwise you will end up with a `list`. Little execution time differences.

```
 mm2N=mm2New[,10:18]
 str(mm2N)
'data.frame':   35487 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ bb    : int  4 6 2 3 3 2 5 2 1 2 ...
 $ vabb  : int  -3 -3 -2 -2 -3 -1 0 0 3 3 ...
 $ bb55  : int  7 6 3 4 4 4 9 2 5 4 ...
 $ vabb55: int  -3 -1 0 -1 -2 -2 -3 0 -1 3 ...
 $ zr    : num  0 -2 -1 1 -1 -1 -1 1 1 0 ...
 $ z55r  : num  -2 -2 0 1 -2 -2 -2 1 -1 1 ...
 $ fechar: num  0 -1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ varr  : num  3 3 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 3 ...
 $ minmax: int  3 0 4 6 6 6 0 6 6 1 ...

 # For solution
 t1=Sys.time()
 for(i in 1:ncol(mm2N)) mm2N[,i]=as.factor(mm2N[,i])
 Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 0.2020121 secs
 str(mm2N)
'data.frame':   35487 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ bb    : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 6 2 3 3 2 5 2 1 2 ...
 $ vabb  : Factor w/ 7 levels "-3","-2","-1",..: 1 1 2 2 1 3 4 4 7 7 ...
 $ bb55  : Factor w/ 8 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 6 5 2 3 3 3 8 1 4 3 ...
 $ vabb55: Factor w/ 7 levels "-3","-2","-1",..: 1 3 4 3 2 2 1 4 3 7 ...
 $ zr    : Factor w/ 5 levels "-2","-1","0",..: 3 1 2 4 2 2 2 4 4 3 ...
 $ z55r  : Factor w/ 5 levels "-2","-1","0",..: 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 4 2 4 ...
 $ fechar: Factor w/ 3 levels "-1","0","1": 2 1 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ varr  : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 3 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 3 ...
 $ minmax: Factor w/ 7 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 4 1 5 7 7 7 1 7 7 2 ...

 #lapply solution
 mm2N=mm2New[,10:18]
 t1=Sys.time()
 mm2N <- lapply(mm2N, as.factor)
 Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 0.209012 secs
 str(mm2N)
List of 9
 $ bb    : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 6 2 3 3 2 5 2 1 2 ...
 $ vabb  : Factor w/ 7 levels "-3","-2","-1",..: 1 1 2 2 1 3 4 4 7 7 ...
 $ bb55  : Factor w/ 8 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 6 5 2 3 3 3 8 1 4 3 ...
 $ vabb55: Factor w/ 7 levels "-3","-2","-1",..: 1 3 4 3 2 2 1 4 3 7 ...
 $ zr    : Factor w/ 5 levels "-2","-1","0",..: 3 1 2 4 2 2 2 4 4 3 ...
 $ z55r  : Factor w/ 5 levels "-2","-1","0",..: 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 4 2 4 ...
 $ fechar: Factor w/ 3 levels "-1","0","1": 2 1 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ varr  : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 3 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 3 ...
 $ minmax: Factor w/ 7 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 4 1 5 7 7 7 1 7 7 2 ...

 #data.frame lapply solution
 mm2N=mm2New[,10:18]
 t1=Sys.time()
 mm2N <- data.frame(lapply(mm2N, as.factor))
 Sys.time()-t1
Time difference of 0.2010119 secs
 str(mm2N)
'data.frame':   35487 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ bb    : Factor w/ 6 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 4 6 2 3 3 2 5 2 1 2 ...
 $ vabb  : Factor w/ 7 levels "-3","-2","-1",..: 1 1 2 2 1 3 4 4 7 7 ...
 $ bb55  : Factor w/ 8 levels "2","3","4","5",..: 6 5 2 3 3 3 8 1 4 3 ...
 $ vabb55: Factor w/ 7 levels "-3","-2","-1",..: 1 3 4 3 2 2 1 4 3 7 ...
 $ zr    : Factor w/ 5 levels "-2","-1","0",..: 3 1 2 4 2 2 2 4 4 3 ...
 $ z55r  : Factor w/ 5 levels "-2","-1","0",..: 1 1 3 4 1 1 1 4 2 4 ...
 $ fechar: Factor w/ 3 levels "-1","0","1": 2 1 3 2 3 3 2 2 3 2 ...
 $ varr  : Factor w/ 5 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 3 3 1 1 1 1 4 1 1 3 ...
 $ minmax: Factor w/ 7 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 4 1 5 7 7 7 1 7 7 2 ...
```

Comment: This will also change all columns. OP asked to change only character columns to factor.

Comment: @SeGa one can put an `if(is.character())` to convert only these columns.

Comment: Just a heads up, you don't need to do `data.frame` with the `lapply` approach when converting all columns. Instead of `mm2N <- data.frame(lapply(mm2N, as.factor))` you can do `mm2N[] <- lapply(mm2N, as.factor)`. Note the `[]`.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1, what does it mean assigning to a `[]`? Isn´t there an implicit conversion to data.frame? Tks!

Comment: @xm1, since a `data.frame` is just a special kind of `list`, you can just re-insert the relevant elements at the specific indices (which is why I had used `[sapply(DF, is.character)]` in my answer). If you use `[]` it replaces everything (provided that the dimensions are correct). Thus, you could do `df <- data.frame(v1 = 1, v2 = 2); df[] <- list("a", "b")` but you can't do `df[] <- list("a", "b", "c")`.

Comment: This works for other objects too and is useful for retaining the structure of the original object. Eg, if you had `m <- matrix(1:2, ncol = 2)` and you wanted to match values to letters, if you did `m <- letters[m]`, dimensions are lost. But if you did `m[] <- letters[m]`, they're retained.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed "[" indexing columns fails to create levels when iterating:

> for ( a_feature in convert.to.factors) {
>    feature.df[a_feature]  <- factor(feature.df[a_feature])  }

It creates, e.g. for the "Status" column:

> Status : Factor w/ 1 level "c(\"Success\", \"Fail\")" : NA NA NA ...

Which is remedied by using "[[" indexing:

> for ( a_feature in convert.to.factors) {
>    feature.df[[a_feature]]  <- factor(feature.df[[a_feature]])  }

Giving instead, as desired:

. Status : Factor w/ 2 levels "Success", "Fail" : 1 1 2 1 ...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Roland 's answer and @Paul de Barros 's comments, I observed to the following conclusion:

```
    df <- data.frame(A = factor(LETTERS[1:5]),
                 B = 1:5, C = as.logical(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1)),
                 D = letters[1:5],
                 E = paste(LETTERS[1:5], letters[1:5]),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   
   df<-as.data.frame(unclass(df),stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
   str(df)
```

Practically and simply seems to work.

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ A: Factor w/ 5 levels "A","B","C","D",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ B: int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ C: logi  TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE
 $ D: Factor w/ 5 levels "a","b","c","d",..: 1 2 3 4 5
 $ E: Factor w/ 5 levels "A a","B b","C c",..: 1 2 3 4 5
```