# dplyr change many data types

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data.frame:

```
dat <- data.frame(fac1 = c(1, 2),
                  fac2 = c(4, 5),
                  fac3 = c(7, 8),
                  dbl1 = c('1', '2'),
                  dbl2 = c('4', '5'),
                  dbl3 = c('6', '7')
                  )
```

To change data types I can use something like

```
l1 <- c("fac1", "fac2", "fac3")
l2 <- c("dbl1", "dbl2", "dbl3")
dat[, l1] <- lapply(dat[, l1], factor)
dat[, l2] <- lapply(dat[, l2], as.numeric)
```

with `dplyr`

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(
    fac1 = factor(fac1), fac2 = factor(fac2), fac3 = factor(fac3),
    dbl1 = as.numeric(dbl1), dbl2 = as.numeric(dbl2), dbl3 = as.numeric(dbl3)
)
```

is there a more elegant (shorter) way in dplyr?

thx
Christof

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use the standard evaluation version of `mutate_each` (which is `mutate_each_`) to change the column classes:

```
dat %>% mutate_each_(funs(factor), l1) %>% mutate_each_(funs(as.numeric), l2)
```

Comment: In this case you could also use `starts_with()`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @hadley. So for the first case that would be `dat %>% mutate_each(funs(factor), starts_with("fac"))` to convert all columns starting with the string "fac" to factor.

Comment: @hadley Is it possible to make the same operation, but in a way that would transform all columns coming after the one the user chooses to get transformed? Not sure my question was clear.

Comment: `mutate_each` is deprecated in latest version, use `mutate_at` instead...

Answer (score 81):

## Edit (as of 2021-03)

As also pointed out in [Eric's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62684051/3250126), `mutate_[at|if|all]` has been superseded by a combination of `mutate()` and `across()`. For reference, I will add the respective pendants to the examples in the original answer (see below):

```
# convert all factor to character
dat %>% mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character))

# apply function (change encoding) to all character columns 
dat %>% mutate(across(where(is.character), 
               function(x){iconv(x, to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")}))

# subsitute all NA in numeric columns
dat %>% mutate(across(where(is.numeric), function(x) tidyr::replace_na(x, 0)))
```

## Original answer

Since Nick's answer is deprecated by now and Rafael's comment is really useful, I want to add this as an Answer. If you want to change **all** `factor` columns to `character` use `mutate_if`:

```
dat %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

Also other functions are allowed. I for instance used `iconv` to change the encoding of all `character` columns:

```
dat %>% mutate_if(is.character, function(x){iconv(x, to = "ASCII//TRANSLIT")})
```

or to substitute all `NA` by 0 in numeric columns:

```
dat %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x){ifelse(is.na(x), 0, x)})
```

Comment: `dat %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)` changes all factor columns to character and is by far the best general answer.

Comment: `funs` is deprecated within dplyr now, so this is now the best answer

Comment: also `dat %>% mutate_if(where(is.factor), as.character)` is even more correct right now

Answer (score 51):

EDIT - The syntax of this answer has been deprecated, [loki's updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49813222/3027540) is more appropriate.

ORIGINAL-

From the bottom of the `?mutate_each` (at least in dplyr 0.5) it looks like  that function, as in @docendo discimus's answer, will be deprecated and replaced with more flexible alternatives `mutate_if`, `mutate_all`, and `mutate_at`.  The one most similar to what @hadley mentions in his comment is probably using `mutate_at`.  Note the order of the arguments is reversed, compared to `mutate_each`, and `vars()` uses `select()` like semantics, which I interpret to mean the `?select_helpers` functions.

```
dat %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with("fac")),funs(factor)) %>%   
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("dbl")),funs(as.numeric))
```

But `mutate_at` can take column numbers instead of a `vars()` argument, and after reading through this page, and looking at the alternatives, I ended up using `mutate_at` but with `grep` to capture many different kinds of column names at once (unless you always have such obvious column names!)

```
dat %>% mutate_at(grep("^(fac|fctr|fckr)",colnames(.)),funs(factor)) %>%
  mutate_at(grep("^(dbl|num|qty)",colnames(.)),funs(as.numeric))
```

I was pretty excited about figuring out `mutate_at` + `grep`, because now one line can work on *lots* of columns.

EDIT - now I see `matches()` in among the select_helpers, which handles regex, so now I like this.

```
dat %>% mutate_at(vars(matches("fac|fctr|fckr")),funs(factor)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(matches("dbl|num|qty")),funs(as.numeric))
```

Another generally-related comment - if you have all your date columns with matchable names, and consistent formats, this is powerful.  In my case, this turns all my YYYYMMDD columns, which were read as numbers, into dates.

```
  mutate_at(vars(matches("_DT$")),funs(as.Date(as.character(.),format="%Y%m%d")))
```

Comment: If you are changing from factor to number, keep in mind `as.numeric` on its own does not work. Factors are stored internally as integers with a table to give the factor level labels. Just using `as.numeric` will only give the internal integer codes. To change from factor to numeric the code should be slightly tweaked. `mutate_at(vars(matches("dbl|num|qty")),function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`

Answer (score 19):

Dplyr `across` function has superseded `_if`, `_at`, and `_all`. See `vignette("colwise")`.

```
dat %>% 
mutate(across(all_of(l1), as.factor),
       across(all_of(l2), as.numeric))
```

Comment: similarly, using column indices: `dat <- dat %>% mutate(across(all_of(names(dat)[1:3]), as.factor), across(all_of(names(dat)[4:6]), as.numeric))`

Answer (score 9):

It's a one-liner with `mutate_at`:

```
dat %>% mutate_at("l1", factor) %>% mutate_at("l2", as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 4):

A more general way of achieving column type transformation is as follows:

If you want to transform all your **factor** columns to **character** columns, e.g., this can be done using one pipe:

```
df %>%  mutate_each_( funs(as.character(.)), names( .[,sapply(., is.factor)] ))
```

Comment: for this case, `df %>% mutate_if(is.factor,as.character)` works (for version of dplyr > 0.5)

Answer (score 2):

For future readers, if you are ok with `dplyr` guessing the column types, you can convert the col types of an entire df as if you were originally reading it in with `readr` and `col_guess()` with

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% type_convert()
```

Answer (score 1):

Or mayby even more simple with `convert` from `hablar`:

```
library(hablar)

dat %>% 
  convert(fct(fac1, fac2, fac3),
          num(dbl1, dbl2, dbl3))
```

or combines with `tidyselect`:

```
dat %>% 
  convert(fct(contains("fac")),
          num(contains("dbl")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df[,1:11] <- sapply(df[,1:11], as.character)
```