# Mutating chosen columns in the data.frame or tibble with dplyr package R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I would like to apply a `mutate` function to multiple columns at once. The columns start with certain string of characters and that is how they should be identified. I would like also to know the solution how to apply it to columns marked by indexing ie. `data_fake[3:4]`. The objective is to remove all the non-numeric characters and convert values to numeric. Can't make it work sadly. Desired result is given at the end of the code. Thanks a lot.

```
data_fake <- data.frame(c("1","2","NA","3,","2","1 only"),c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        c("23","3 bundles","4","5","NA","1"), c("3","5 packs","6","78","7","8"))
colnames(data_fake) <- c("AB foo ab", "AB foo bc", "CD foo ab","CD foo bc")

data_fake <- as_tibble(data_fake)

data_fake %>%
        select(starts_with("CD foo")) %>% 
        mutate(as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9]", "")))

data_fake_results <- as_tibble(data.frame(c("1","2","NA","3,","2","1 only"),c(1,2,3,4,5,6),
                        c(23,3,4,5,NA,1), c(3,5,6,78,7,8)))
```

Comment: See `?mutate_if`. And you need to give `gsub` three arguments, the `pattern`, the `replacement`, and `x` the string to look in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [dplyr change many data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27668266/dplyr-change-many-data-types)

Comment: At the post that I marked as a duplicate, some of the answers are outdated, but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38428978/5325862) uses current `dplyr` selectors

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `mutate_at`

```
library(tidyverse)
data_fake %>%
    mutate_at(vars(3:4), funs(as.numeric(str_remove(., "\\s+[a-z]+"))))
```

---

Or use `parse_number`

```
data_fake %>%
     mutate_at(3:4, parse_number)
```

If we want to match the column names in `mutate_at`

```
data_fake %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with("CD")), parse_number)
```

Comment: Fantastic! And how to do exactly the same thing but choosing columns by the title (here they should start with "CD foo")?

Comment: @MIH `mutate_at(vars(starts_with("CD"))`

Comment: @MIH You can find all the functions used to specify columns in `?select`. The scoped (`*_at`) versions of `mutate`, `transmute`, `rename`, etc use the same specifying functions as `select`