# Data wrangling with R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a long list of variables that I want to convert to factors. So, I did this:

```
factor_df <- original_df %>%
                  select(PhoneService:PaymentMethod) %>%
                  map(as.factor)
```

I get all the variables from PhoneService to PaymentMethod as factors.
How do I make this `factor_df` to attach to `original_df` again, so that the `original_df` has all the appropriate data types?

Comment: Do you want to do the conversion for all character variables? If so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39582737/210673 for use of `mutate_if`.

Comment: Alternatively, look at `mutate_at` to convert only specific columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
original_df %>%
    mutate_at(vars(PhoneService:PaymentMethod), as.factor)
```

The `dplyr::mutate_at()` function allows you to specify which variables or `vars()` you wish to apply a single function or multiple functions with `funs()`.

Source:
https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html