# Converting all strings to factors in dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe where I read a csv like so to convert characters to factors

```
sim_df <- read.csv("test.csv", stringsAsFactors=T)
```

How can I do this without the stringsAsFactors argument and use dplyr syntax?

For example it would look something like so..

```
sim_df <- read.csv("text.csv") %>% mutate(<something to convert all string columns to factors>)
```

Thanks!

Comment: `%>%mutate(across(where(is.character), factor))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert all data frame character columns to factors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637360/convert-all-data-frame-character-columns-to-factors)

Comment: Can you do a mutate state with multiple across statements?