R is not displaying the correct summary of my data when using the summary() command. How do I fix this?
So I'm brand new to R and I'm currently using the swirl package as a tutorial for it. I have a dataframe named plants where when I am trying to do the command
summary(plants)
my output differs from the expectation and I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this kind of issue since it's not based on my data being incorrect.
My output:

Output from slide screenshot:

The difference to highlight is that the columns with data made up of characters does not display.
Since the tutorial doesn't allow me to proceed unless I've exactly done the correct steps, I don't have issues with my data or the code itself since i even forced swirl to write my code for me. I'm not sure how to trouble shoot something like this. I've already made sure my R version is the most up to date and this lecture slide is from 2021.  Does anyone know if the summary() command's functionality has been updated and a different command would yield what I'm looking to mimic.

The issue is that the string variables in your data are factors in the example.  This is probably best fixed during read in of the data so if you used read.table() (or its convenient wrappers read.csv() etc.) ensure you include the argument stringsAsFactors = TRUE.  The default for this argument changed several years ago (was TRUE by default, but is now FALSE) which might explain your issue.

I think your right because swirl mentions factor variables afterward being the classification being used so your explanation makes sense. Thank you!

Side note. Do you know if there is a basic command to change my strings into factors after the data has already imported? Since I didn't import this data but it was preloaded by the package I don't know how to adjust it.

See if the answers here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637360/convert-all-data-frame-character-columns-to-factors help.
